# Refactoring PHP foreach to a current element only (without loop)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a foreach loop which returns a string. However, I would like to refactor this code to work without a loop, and should give the string for the current element.

```
foreach ($orderWC->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
    // Here you get your data
    $rank = wc_get_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Rank', true);
    var_dump($rank);
}
```

I have tried `current();`, but it returns a var_dump of `bool(false)`.

```
$item_id = current($orderWC->get_items());
$rank = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Rank', true );
```

Is my logic flawed and this isn't possible at all, or am I just doing it the wrong way?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My actual problem is that the var_dump inside the foreach loop returns the values found on the image below, which has a duplicate. It lists Test1 and Test2 twice, whereas I only need them once (and access them separately).
[image: duplicate var_dump]

This is why I figured that I don't need to loop them - to avoid duplicates.

Comment: what "current element" means to you in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the OP still unclear since could be the case where `$orderWC->get_items()` is indeed returning duplicated values (which you don't mention anywhere) you could use [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicates before loop through them. Ex:

```
$arr = array_unique($orderWC->get_items());
foreach ($arr as $item_id => $item) {
    $rank = wc_get_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Rank', true);
    var_dump($rank);
}
```